# how do I use a vslider as the scrollbar for a list?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flexbuilder

how do I use a vslider as the scrollbar for a list? I've got this, but can't figure it out from here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"     
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  height="100%" width="100%">

<s:VSlider id="slider" minimum="0" maximum="{listy.height}" liveDragging="true"/>

<s:List id="listy" width="50%" height="100">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout id="vLayout" verticalScrollPosition="{slider.value}" />
    </s:layout>

    <mx:ArrayCollection>
        <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
        <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
    </mx:ArrayCollection>
</s:List>
</s:Application>
```

EDIT: Using Nate's suggestion below, I've now got it working but it shows both the vslider as well as the default scrollbar. How do I hide the default scrollbar? I tried setting verticalScrollPolicy="off" but that didn't work. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's totally possible, and I aims to proove it!   All joking aside, here it is working with just some simple binding, you were very close!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"     
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  height="100%" width="100%">

    <s:Group>
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout/>
        </s:layout>

        <s:List id="listy" width="50%" height="100" 
                change="slider.value=listy.layout.verticalScrollPosition" creationComplete="
                listy.dataGroup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, function():void{
                    slider.value=listy.layout.verticalScrollPosition}
                );">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout id="vLayout" verticalScrollPosition="{slider.value}" />
            </s:layout>

            <mx:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
            </mx:ArrayCollection>
        </s:List>

        <s:VSlider id="slider" height="{listy.height}" 
                   minimum="0" maximum="{listy.dataGroup.contentHeight - listy.height}" 
                   showDataTip="false" scaleY="-1" liveDragging="true"/> 

    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

Ping me if you don't get the how and why of it  :)

Comment: very nice. If I use the my arrow keys to scroll down the list, however, the vslider doesn't follow

Comment: BAH DETAILS! J/k - I edited for you, notice the addition of :  change="slider.value=listy.layout.verticalScrollPosition" in the list component.  This says that when the selected item changes, update the vslider position.  Piece o cake

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the mouse doesnt work?  The slider is still usable, the arrow keys move the slider, is there something else?

Comment: when I use the mouse wheel to scroll down the list the vslider doesn't move (but the scrollbar does).

Comment: i'll take a look at this for you later today, been on vacation!  w00t!

Comment: Added code to update vslider position when scrolled with mouse wheel.  Enjoy!

Comment: thx. Now, how do I hide the default scrollbar w/out disabling the ability to scroll w/ the mouse? I tried setting verticalscrollpolicy="off" but that disables scrolling w/ the mouse. thx!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can suggest you to reach your goal is skinning. Create a skin for `VScrollBar` which looks the same as `VSlider`. Then create custom `Scroller` skin (take `spark.skins.spark.ScrollerSkin` as a pattern) and assign these scroller skins there. Then create your custom `List` skin (based on `spark.skins.spark.ListSkin`) and assign `Scroller` skin to the `Scroller` there.

In the case if you (for some reason) have to use original `VSlider` you'll need to write your own `Scroller` with sliders and use it in your `List` skin.

I suggest you the first method.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I use a vslider as the scrollbar for a list? I've got this, but
>   can't figure it out from here:

Unfortunately, I do not believe this is possible without significant rework.

The list is implemented, inside the ListSkin, as a Scroller and a DataGroup.
The Scroller has two skin parts, the verticalScrollBar and the horizontalScrollBar.  You want to replace the veritcalScrollBar with a VSlider.

Unfortunately, the skin requires a VScrollBar instance and there is no interface class you can use to replace one with the other.  (The Scroller implementation was implemented using the Flex 2/3 approach in order to make it impossibly hard to extend)

You're stuck using black magic to make this work.

However, trying to skin the VSCrollBar to look like a VSlider does seem to be like your best bet.